# Can you define a function prototype in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to be able to structure my code for my Inno Setup project but I am forced to move code around because you can't call a function unless it is defined first.

Is there a way to declare a prototype at the top so that I don't get the *"Unknown identifier"* error and so that I can structure my code in logical blocks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Pascal (including a Pascal Script used in Inno Setup), you can define a function prototype (aka forward declaration) using a `forward` keyword:

```pascal
procedure ProcA(ParamA: Integer); forward;

procedure ProcB;
begin
  ProcA(1);
end;

procedure ProcA(ParamA: Integer);
begin
  { some code }
end;
```

See [Forward declared functions](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse97.html).