# Can I create my own classes or units in Inno Setup?

Tags: class, oop, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to know if it's possible in Inno Setup to define my own units or classes - with both fields (just like defining a record) and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can define only:

- structures (`record` keyword) - fields only, and
- interfaces (`interface` keyword) - abstract methods only - for COM/ActiveX.

But you cannot implement classes (fields and methods).

The Pascal Script does not even recognize the `class` keyword.

---

Not even `unit`s. The Inno Setup Pascal Script is just a single block of code. There's no really any point trying to hide some implementation/code.

---

If you just want to organize the code somehow, you can use the [`#include` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=include) of [Inno Setup pre-processor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to split the code into files.

You can have a header/interface-like file with [prototypes/forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30073545/850848) of the "public" functions/procedures and implementation-like file with the implementation and "private" functions/procedures.

The interface-like file (say `header.iss`):

```pascal
procedure PublicProc; forward;
```

The implementation-like file (say `impl.iss`):

```pascal
procedure PrivateProc;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure PublicProc;
begin
  PrivateProc;
end;
```

And use it like:

```pascal
[Code]

#include "header.iss"

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  { Here we can use the PublicProc, but not PrivateProc }
end;

#include "impl.iss"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know anything about units? Or anything close to the concept of encapsulation (without having to embed a dll)?