# Inno Setup having multiple UpdateReadyMemo events

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using Inno Setup 6.2. I need to add a custom contents to *"Ready to Install"* page. For that I'm using

```pascal
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
```

According to the documentation, function's return value is the displayed string/contents.
This works fine so far.

I've added a third party component (https://github.com/DomGries/InnoDependencyInstaller) which also implements the event and updates the page content too.

```pascal
<event('UpdateReadyMemo')>
function Dependency_Internal3(const Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
```

Note the event identifier.

Documentation also points out that those events are called in order of their definition,
stopping in case one of them returns a non-empty string.
As the return string is the displayed text, this behavior prevents having multiple `UpdateReadyMemo` events where each provides a part of the summary page.

Currently I removed the event identifier and call the function manually

```pascal
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var
    s: string;
begin
    s := Dependency_Internal3(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo);

    ...
      
    Result := s
end;
```

Is there a better way without modifying and without accessing internal implementation of third party code to get a summary content from multiple modules?

thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

As Inno Setup stops on the `UpdateReadyMemo` function that returns something, you just need to make sure your implementation is *before* the InnoDependencyInstaller implementation.

But as you need to be able to call the `Dependency_Internal3`, before it  is declared, you need to [`forward` declare it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30073545/850848).

Something like this:

```pascal
[Code]

function Dependency_Internal3(
  const Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo,
  MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String; forward;

function UpdateReadyMemo(
  Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo,
  MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var
  s: string;
begin
  s :=
    Dependency_Internal3(
      Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, 
      MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo);

  // ...
      
  Result := s
end;

// Include the (unmodified) InnoDependencyInstaller only now
#include "CodeDependencies.iss"
```

---

*If you need even better solution, you will need to ask the library authors to make their API better.*

Comment: The idea is not to touch internal third party code at all. In the next release Dependency_Internal3 might be renamed to Dependency_InternalWhatEver and I don't want to change my code

Comment: Well, you ask for too much. I do not think there's any better solution. No change to thirdparty code is needed. And if they rename the function, your code will break, so you will know that you need to update it. If you need better solution, you will need to ask the library authors to make their API better.